# How to define structure in iOS XCode for JSON?

Tags: ios, json, xcode, struct, declare

Being new to iOS, XCode I'm trying to create a structure to represent JSON data.  However, regardless of what I try for defining "segments" (which consists of a int and an array of strings) XCode just errors out and when I try to follow suggested fixes it just generates other errors.

Anybody know how to actually define a structure for JSON that is named, e.g., not using "ANY", since all the name-value pairs and data types are known?

**Example XCODE** (one variation shown below, though dozens have been tried and generates errors):

```
struct Information: Decodable {
    var entry: [Entry]
}
struct Entry: Decodable {
    var section: Int
    ***ERROR HERE ->*** var segments: Array<var id: Int, var values: Array<String>>
}
```

**Example JSON:**

```
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "section": 1,
      "segments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "values": ["1", "2", "3"]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "values": [ "4", "5", "6" ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "section": 2,
      "segments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "values": ["7", "8", "9"]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "values": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as on the top level: You have to create a struct for the lower level.

```
struct Information: Decodable {
    let entry: [Entry]
}
struct Entry: Decodable {
    let section: Int
    let segments: [Segment]
}
struct Segment: Decodable {
    let id: Int 
    let values: [String]
}
```

Comment: vadian, the suggestion works great!  I had no idea it had to be broken down like that for the inner parts of the structure.  I'm off to learn more about this new XCode (new for me, at least), thanks again!